# What there is reason behind chunk size in rendering engine?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, browser

While reading through on how browser works I found that rendering engine can parses the requested document in the chunks of `8kB` I was wondering what might be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's beacuse of [TCP/IP default buffer size](https://books.google.it/books?dq=8KB&id=cGVqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=8KB&f=false): 8kB